# Why does this CSS place the blue box in the right corner instead of after the green box?

Tags: html, css

I have this html and CSS:

```
<div style="background-color:Red; width:200px; height:200px;">

<div style="background-color:Blue; width:50px; height:50px; float:right;">aa</div>

<div style="background-color:Green; width:50px; height:50px;">aa</div>
```

I thought it would place the blue box after the green one (flow layout) but its moved it right over to the edge of the red container, which is really wierd..Any ideas why it doesnt flow?

Comment: you have three open divs and two close divs,this is wierd..

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing tag for the first `<div>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'float' means 'move to that side and allow anything following to appear on the opposite side'

Since you are floating blue right, it appears on the far right hand side of its container.

Since there is room next to Blue and Blue is floating, Green appears next to Blue. Green appears at the left hand side because it has nothing to alter its horizontal position from the default (such as margins, or touching Green).

Answer (score 1):

Because that is what `float: right` does.

According to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats):

> A floated box is shifted to the left
>   or right until its outer edge touches
>   the containing block edge or the outer
>   edge of another float.

Answer (score 1):

Because `float` moves the element as far as possible to the right *and* to the top.

Here are the precise rules that govern the behavior of floats ([from W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position)):

1. The left outer edge of a left-floating box may not be to the left of the left edge of its containing block. An analogous rule holds for right-floating elements.
2. If the current box is left-floating, and there are any left-floating boxes generated by elements earlier in the source document, then for each such earlier box, either the left outer edge of the current box must be to the right of the right outer edge of the earlier box, or its top must be lower than the bottom of the earlier box. Analogous rules hold for right-floating boxes.
3. The right outer edge of a left-floating box may not be to the right of the left outer edge of any right-floating box that is next to it. Analogous rules hold for right-floating elements.
4. A floating box's outer top may not be higher than the top of its containing block. When the float occurs between two collapsing margins, the float is positioned as if it had an otherwise empty anonymous block parent taking part in the flow. The position of such a parent is defined by the rules in the section on margin collapsing.
5. **The outer top of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top of any block or floated box generated by an element earlier in the source document.**
6. The outer top of an element's floating box may not be higher than the top of any line-box containing a box generated by an element earlier in the source document.
7. A left-floating box that has another left-floating box to its left may not have its right outer edge to the right of its containing block's right edge. (Loosely: a left float may not stick out at the right edge, unless it is already as far to the left as possible.) An analogous rule holds for right-floating elements.
8. **A floating box must be placed as high as possible.**
9. A left-floating box must be put as far to the left as possible, a right-floating box as far to the right as possible. **A higher position is preferred over one that is further to the left/right.**

As you can see, floated boxes tend to go to the top. If you were to float other boxes, then the order would matter. If only one floats, it shoves all the rest around.

Answer (score 0):

Float moves an item to the far left or right of the parent element.

Why not place it after the green div, and apply float: left to both?